# Кроссдоменные запросы Post,Get через javascript и Java?

Tags: javascript, java

Уже много дней пытаюсь понять 2 вещи:

1. Принципиальная разница Json от Jsonp при запросах? В том,что Jsonp является прокладкой Json, более менее понятно, а вот при кроссдоменных запросах, почему обычным Json не получиться?
2. Почему используя например Java, с ее например классом HttpRequest и т.д. проблем с Post запросами к Api или к серверных файлам .php проблем  нет, а в случае написания клиента на javascript(jquery) нужно что то продумывать, т.е. если я правильно понимаю, в языках таких как Java нет такого понятия как кроссдомен, вся процедура запроса стандартная, и ответ (response) придет в любом случае?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ простой - это все для безопасности. Так как JavaScript работает на стороне пользователя, то разработчики браузеров стараются обезопасить пользователя от вредного кода.

1. Браузер может скачать и выполнить скрипт расположенный на другом сервере, но не может сделать запрос на другой сервер. jsonp - это json обернутый в вызов функции. То есть браузер скачает это файл и попробует запусти функцию. Сама функция должна быть описана ранее.
2. И PHP, и Java (за исключением апплета) выполняются вне браузера и поэтому у них нет таких ограничений. Более того, если вы запустите JavaScript на Node.js, то там тоже не будет этих ограничений.
3. Java applet точно так же ограничен. Так еще он должен быть подписан, что бы браузер его запустил.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ,только одно все же не понятно,вот например есть Веб-сервисы всякие API ,ну скажем google,вские или еще какие-нибудь,как с ними взаимодействует браузер,по сути те же  самые кроссдоменные запросы?????Если да,то как они обходят безопасности все??

Comment: Никак. Они не обходят. Можно добавить CORS и разрешить кроссдоменные запросы.

Comment: Т.е., например Google map v2 API -использует CORS??Для того ,чтобы можно было им пользоватсяь...

Comment: Вы всегда можете править свои посты: для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего поста. Важную информацию лучше включать непосредственно в исходное сообщение.

Comment: Уточните какие именно запросы к Google map API вы имеете в виде

Comment: например со своего сайта на Google api maps v2,для отображения карты,меток ,координат!!!

Comment: как именно вы делаете этот запрос?

Comment: </script>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>  здесь мы передаем Ключ гугловский и колбэк к штатной фунции инициализации

Comment: на тег script ограничение на кроссдоменные запросы не действует. поэтому и возможно использование jsonp.